# Applications not showing on kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

I installed the kubuntu-desktop following [this site](http://www.tecmint.com/install-kde-plasma-5-in-linux/) on my ubuntu os (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
). Now when i use kubuntu-desktop instead of unity I cannot view my applications on start menu

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by installing [muon](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=muon&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) by running `sudo apt-get install muon`. Its a possibility that I just rebooted the system and solved the issue, but the first thing to do is to install `muon`.